Are there infinitely many Munchausen numbers?
I came across the concept of Munchausen numbers on Instagram and it's sparked my curiosity.
An example of a Munchausen number is:
$$3^3+4^4+3^3+5^5=3435$$
My question is are there an infinite number of Munchausen numbers, is there a proof?

See this

See also OEIS sequence A046253 and references there.

This is not only a duplicate , but also contextless and instead of being answered , it should therefore be closed.

The real question is, "Are there infinitely many Munchausen patients?" lol

Let's say a Munchausen number has $d$ digits (with non-zero leading digit). On one hand, the number is at least $10^{d-1}$. On the other hand, the number is at most $9^9d$ by the Munchausen property. Thus, you must have the inequality $10^{d-1} \leqslant 9^9d$. Now, this inequality cannot hold true for sufficiently large $d$, so we have a bound on the number of digits in a Munchausen number. In particular, this implies that there are only finitely many Munchausen numbers. Note that this proof applies in general to any base.

For historical context, the observation that there are finitely-many Munchausen numbers for a given base was the main result of Daan van Berkel's 2009 preprint in which the "Munchausen" designation was introduced. (That said, his proof of such was a bit more involved than the one provided here.)

Indeed $d=11$ is big enough in decimal.  For general base $b\ge 2$ you find $d= b+1$ is big enough since then $b^d=b^{(b+1)-1}=b^b>(b+1)(b-1)b^{b-2}\ge (b+1)(b-1)^{b-1}=d(b-1)^{b-1}$ and the gap only grows for larger $d$

One further historical point: the argument used here is that appearing in Kureš 2021 which lulu linked as a comment to the OP.
